# WinVerifyTrust fails rarely

Tags: winverifytrust

I use winverifytrust to validate signature.

I am verifying using WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2. But rarely it has returned "NO SIGNATURE FOUND".  I am unable to simulate the issue.

I am getting feedback  that this is happening in some users. One feedback has a log which indicates that the 1st call to WinVerifyTrust for a file succeeds and the second call to the same file has failed.

The code i used is exactly

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Any idea what may have caused the failure. Same call to the same file has succeeded once and failed next.

Comment: This might help you. Ref: [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3054204/update-lets-the-winverifytrust-function-in-windows-server-2012-work-wi) 

@user738471

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MS example you linked if you encounter `TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE` then you need to examine `GetLastError()` for a further `TRUST_E_` error code.

Their logic for `TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE` also includes;

```
 else 
 {
   // The signature was not valid or there was an error 
   // opening the file.
```

So it seems that an IO error could also cause this (a locked file could explain the intermittency) either way `GetLastError()` should elucidate.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when calling WinVerifyTrust on Windows Server 2008 with a file signed with only SHA-256,

**which isn't supported by default on Server 2008, it expects signatures that use SHA-1**.

Answer (score -3):

http://winwiki.org/wiki/wikimeta.php?kw=Error+Trust_e_nosignature%280x800b0100%29

The Error Trust_e_nosignature(0x800b0100) error may be caused by windows system files damage.

This article contains information that shows you how to fix Error Trust_e_nosignature(0x800b0100) both (manually) and (automatically).